# Ionic 2 Datetime Change Date Region

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to use Ionic 2 Datetime component in my application But my problem is the target date format is not gregorian and it's Jalali(persian) date format. So I wondering that if any way to change the region of datetime. I wrote a service for change gregorian date to jalali but I don't know that is it possible to change datetime to work with this or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the library moment js, it seems to have a plugin with the calendar kind you look for, [see here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/jalaali/). And for the display of the picker, maybe if you use the [native datepicker](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/date-picker/) plugin, you'll have a correct display of your calendar (assuming those are managed by android or ios).